# How to find the Image of the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I tried to find the image of the linear transformation: $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{P}_3$ defined:

$T\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\ b\\ c\end{array}\right] = (a+b)x^3+(-b+c)x^2+(a+c)x+(2a+b)$

I define a function of degree 3 as $mx^3+nx^2+px+q$ and equal it to $(a+b)x^3+(-b+c)x^2+(a+c)x+(2a+b)$ , but i get confused. Please, help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please provide more details as to the nature of your confusion.

Comment: Take any basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. There's a theorem that states: *$Im(T)$ is the span of the images of the selected basis*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ s.t. $B=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$

$T(1,0,0)=x^3+x+2$

$T(0,1,0)=x^3-x^2-1$

$T(0,0,1)=x^2+x$

The image vectors of basis elements also spans the image space so $span\{Im(T)\}=\{x^3+x+2,x^3-x^2-1,x^2+x\}$. Can you investigate the linear independence of the vectors in above set?

If they are LI then basis of $Im(T)$ is same as $span\{Im(T)\}$ otherwise, a basis must be a $2-$element subset like $\{x^3+x+2, x^2+x\}$ (*why?*).

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Diana....my pleasure!